# Input in Bootstrap Modal not editable

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have created a bootstrap modal with a input text as shown in the following image. The input gets focus on click(sometimes), however when I try to enter text, nothing happens. 
I am using angular 4, and in my project structure I have a component which has another modal dialog - and the inputs work fine, however the child of that component has this modal (which is appended to the document body on show) and the input is not editable.

[image: Modal]

[image: Inspect element]

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Code for modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="boardDetailsModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit timeline</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveTimeline()">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="close()">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Code for showing modal:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    let self = this;
    self.element.appendTo("body").modal('show');
}
```

Comment: @Iancovici I have included jQuery in angular, so the other modal in the parent component is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a small typo.

Change your input to:

```
<input type="text" />
```

Notice the forward slash.

Comment: Doesn't change anything.

Comment: I was listening to keyboard events and therefore preventing default. It works without event.preventDefault().